# flake8/pylint fails in Tox testing environment, raises InvocationError

Tags: python, testing, tox, flake8

I've been learning about how to do testing in tox for my python project.

I have (what should be) a fairly standard tox initialization file that looks like the following:

```
[tox]
envlist=py27,flake8
...
[testenv:flake8]
deps=flake8
commands=flake8 library # 'library' is temp. name of project
```

Everything looks normal, all the test works, and even the flake8 output comes through (output below). However, tox raises an InvocationError (it does the same for testing using pylint)

```
flake8 recreate: /Users/shostakovich/projects/project_templates/library/.tox/flake8
flake8 installdeps: flake8
flake8 inst: /Users/shostakovich/projects/project_templates/library/.tox/dist/library-0.1.0.zip
flake8 installed: flake8==2.4.1,library==0.1.0,mccabe==0.3,pep8==1.5.7,pyflakes==0.8.1,wheel==0.24.0
library/__main__.py:12:1: F401 'os' imported but unused
library/__main__.py:13:1: F401 're' imported but unused
...
ERROR: InvocationError: '/Users/shostakovich/projects/project_templates/library/.tox/flake8/bin/flake8 library'
```

I am running tox 2.0.2 on MaxOSX 10.9.5. The problem goes away if I just call flake8 or pylint directly (the version of flake8 is shown above).

Answer (score 29):

`tox` doesn't fail, it works!

Your `flake8` source code check has findings and therefore `tox` exits with failures, that's your test result. Fix the findings and your done!

You may configure the `flake8` run to ignore specific codes with a section in your `tox.ini`. From the [flake8 docs](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/):

```
[flake8]
ignore = E226,E302,E41
```

There are more options you may be interested in, e.g. `select = ...` for whitelisting enabled code checks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also tell flake8 to exit without failure, even if the test results are not perfect. This will suppress the misleading InvocationError. Just add to your command `--exit-zero`, so for example:

```
commands=flake8 library --exit-zero
```